# How can I get the data from a data product using Platform of Trust?

Tags: api, platform-of-trust

I could find here list of products https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/products/v1, but wanted to see some sample data from a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [the guide for consuming data via Broker](https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/consume-data-products/).

There are also the following extra tools at the moment:

1. Python script for experimenting with Broker => [find it here](https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/integrate-data-source-60-minutes/#step-8-test-your-data-product) and customize the variables secret, app_token
2. Insomnia workspace which uses a plugin for pot-signature generation => [find it here](https://github.com/PlatformOfTrust/rest-client-packages/tree/master/insomnia)
3. Postman collection which has pre-request script which generates x-pot-signature => [find it here](https://github.com/PlatformOfTrust/rest-client-packages/tree/master/postman/v1)